# How do I check which player moves in my connect four game?

Tags: java

I am trying to create a method/ while loop which checks to see which player moves. For now I check to see which play moves in a for loop. I am trying to make my code a bit more clear and concise. Here is the main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


            try (Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)) {
                int height = 6, width = 8, moves = height * width;
                ConnectFour board = new ConnectFour(width, height);
                System.out.println("Use 0-" + (width - 1) + " to choose a column.");
                System.out.println(board);



                for (int player = 0; moves-- > 0; player = 1 - player) {  // Here is where i check to see who plays 
                    char symbol = players[player];
                    board.chooseAndDrop(symbol, input);
                    System.out.println(board);
                    if (board.isWinningPlay()) {
                        System.out.println("Player " + symbol + " wins!");
                        return;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Game over, no winner.");
            }


        }
```

I was thinking more along the lines of:

```
                    int playerNb = 0;
                    while (thegamestarted)
                    {
                        if (playerNb == 0)
                            // Get user input
                        else
                            // Get second player input

                        // Process the input
                        // Change playerNb to 1 or 0
                    }
```

Below is the full code:

```
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.stream.Collectors;
    import java.util.stream.IntStream;

    public class ConnectFour {
        private static final char[] players = new char[] { 'X', 'O' };

        private final int width, height;
        private final char[][] grid;
        private int lastCol = -1, lastTop = -1;

        public ConnectFour(int width, int height) {
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
            this.grid = new char[height][];
            for (int h = 0; h < height; h++) {
                Arrays.fill(this.grid[h] = new char[width], '.');
            }
        }

        public String toString() {
            return IntStream.range(0, this.width)
                            .mapToObj(Integer::toString)
                            .collect(Collectors.joining()) + "\n" +
                   Arrays.stream(this.grid)
                         .map(String::new)
                         .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
        }

        /**
         * Prompts the user for a column, repeating until a valid
         * choice is made.
         */
        public void chooseAndDrop(char symbol, Scanner input) {
            do {
                System.out.print("\nPlayer " + symbol + " turn: ");
                int col = input.nextInt();

                if (! (0 <= col && col < this.width)) {
                    System.out.println("Column must be between 0 and " +
                                       (this.width - 1));
                    continue;
                }
                for (int h = this.height - 1; h >= 0; h--) {
                    if (this.grid[h][col] == '.') {
                        this.grid[this.lastTop=h][this.lastCol=col] = symbol;
                        return;
                    }
                }

                System.out.println("Column " + col + " is full.");
            } while (true);
        }

        /**
         * Detects whether the last chip played was a winning move.
         */
        public boolean isWinningPlay() {
            if (this.lastCol == -1) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("No move has been made yet");
            }
            char sym = this.grid[this.lastTop][this.lastCol];
            String streak = String.format("%c%c%c%c", sym, sym, sym, sym);
            return contains(this.horizontal(), streak) ||
                   contains(this.vertical(), streak) ||
                   contains(this.slashDiagonal(), streak) ||
                   contains(this.backslashDiagonal(), streak);
        }

        /**
         * The contents of the row containing the last played chip.
         */
        private String horizontal() {
            return new String(this.grid[this.lastTop]);
        }

        /**
         * The contents of the column containing the last played chip.
         */
        private String vertical() {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(this.height);
            for (int h = 0; h < this.height; h++) {
                sb.append(this.grid[h][this.lastCol]);
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }

        /**
         * The contents of the "/" diagonal containing the last played chip
         * (coordinates have a constant sum).
         */
        private String slashDiagonal() {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(this.height);
            for (int h = 0; h < this.height; h++) {
                int w = this.lastCol + this.lastTop - h;
                if (0 <= w && w < this.width) {
                    sb.append(this.grid[h][w]);
                }
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }

        /**
         * The contents of the "\" diagonal containing the last played chip
         * (coordinates have a constant difference).
         */
        private String backslashDiagonal() {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(this.height);
            for (int h = 0; h < this.height; h++) {
                int w = this.lastCol - this.lastTop + h;
                if (0 <= w && w < this.width) {
                    sb.append(this.grid[h][w]);
                }
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }

        private static boolean contains(String haystack, String needle) {
            return haystack.indexOf(needle) >= 0;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try (Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)) {
                int height = 6, width = 8, moves = height * width;
                ConnectFour board = new ConnectFour(width, height);
                System.out.println("Use 0-" + (width - 1) + " to choose a column.");
                System.out.println(board);

                for (int player = 0; moves-- > 0; player = 1 - player) {
                    char symbol = players[player];
                    board.chooseAndDrop(symbol, input);
                    System.out.println(board);
                    if (board.isWinningPlay()) {
                        System.out.println("Player " + symbol + " wins!");
                        return;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Game over, no winner.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the question? Have you run these in your debugger? What was the result? Did it work? If it didn't, can you identify where the behavior deviates from your expectation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a bit difficult to tell what you want from your code, but the absolute simplest way to keep track of what player it is, is to keep track of the turn number, and check if it is even or odd with the modulus function

This is just a brief bit of psuedocode to show you how you can tell what the turn is with simple math. You will have to adapt it to your own needs. You can see that it will only be "Player 2"'s turn on an even turn number where the turn number divided by 2 has no remainder. Just remember to increment the turn after every move.

There's no "good" answer. You're the one writing the code, you can decide whose turn it is, you just have to keep track of it.

```
int turn = 1;

for ( ) {
    if (turn % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.println("Player 2");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Player 1");
    }
    turn++;
}
```

Comment: Hey mate thanks for your response. I'm trying to check to see whose turn it is. If it is player 1 then player1  make a move. Else if it's player 2 player 2 makes a move.

Comment: You're keeping track of what move it is, you can extrapolate my example to work with "move" instead of "turn" number. If "move 1" always belongs to player 1, then you should always know who is playing if you know the move.